# Are there functions which are neither convex nor concave everywhere but are continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

By convex/cave I mean by the definition for an interval $(x,y)$ of $f$ is convex iff $f(\frac{a+b}{2})\geq\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$ and is concave if $f(\frac{a+b}{2})\leq\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$ where $a,b\in(x,y)$. This is merely so that the function does not have to be differentiable.

If it's not possible to have a function be continuous but not convex or concave on any nonempty interval, is it possible to construct a function which is not convex or concave on any nonempty interval? Has one already been created?

If it is possible to have a function be continuous but not convex or concave on any nonempty interval, is it possible to construct it? Has one already been created?

Is it possible to have one of these functions be differentiable once?

Comment: Presumably you want not convex/concave on any *finite* interval of positive length.  The Weierstrass function should fit this bill.  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/WeierstrassFunction.svg  (article at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function)

Comment: Sorry, I worded that wrong. I meant nonempty, not infinite.

Comment: Also, can there be such a function with a first derivative?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies the Weierstrass function doesn't work because it has local extrema; take $a$  and $b$ at equal, sufficiently small, distances to the left and right of such a local extremum, e.g. a maximum, then we have $(f(a)+f(b))/2 < f((a+b)/2)$. As the definition of convexity or concavity is based on the comparison of two reals, the outcome can only be less, equal or greater; quartum non datur.  What would be needed, is a defintion based on limits.

Comment: For the two points you chose, yes $(f(a)+f(b))/2 < f((a+b)/2)$ where $c=(a+b)/2$ is the location of the maximum. But between $a$ and $c$ there are local maxima and minima so the function is neither convex nor concave on $(a,b)$ or even $(a,c).$ In fact the function on $(a,b)$ when observed at great enough magnification will look similar to (part of) the original function.

Comment: @ManfredWeis The question clearly speaks of concavity/convexity in an _interval_; your example doesn't imply that the condition holds for _all_ $(a,b)$ in a small interval around even that local extremum.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is well known that almost every path of a Brownian motion is nowhere monotone (i.e., not monotone on any interval). Hence the primitive (antiderivative) of almost every path is continuously differentiable but nowhere convex or concave.

Comment: It is also not hard to rig up a nowhere monotone function by an inductive construction, which will be a little more elementary - take a piecewise linear function, and repeatedly add a new vertex near an existing vertex either slightly above or below, then form the piecewise function with the new vertices. Also add vertices in the middle of any big gaps. By choosing the vertices close enough, the sequence is uniformly convergent, hence the limit is continuous, and we can choose the vertices sequentially to kill monotonicity on every intereval.

Answer (score 7):

Any convex (or concave) function on a convex set is locally Lipschitz, thus in particular a function $f$ which is convex or concave on an interval is absolutely continuous. Now if you construct a function which is continuous on $[a,b]$ but not absolutely continuous on any subinterval, this should fit the bill.